# How to define a proper data structure for a parameter set

Tags: f#

I need a data structure for the following:

In a device that has memory slots, each of the slots has a set of parameters. These parameters have different types. The list of possible parameters is fixed, so there is no need for generic flexibility à la »Support of arbitrary parameters without change«. Also, for each parameter, the structure of the contents is known. Typical use cases are the retrieval and modification of one specific parameter as well as a transformation of the complete parameter set into a different (but already defined) data structure.

The natural choice of F# data structure would be a sum type like this:

```
type SomeParameterContentType = { Field1 : string, Field2 : int }
type SomeOtherParameterContentType = { Other1 : bool option, Other2 : double }

type Parameter =
    | SomeParameter of SomeParameterContentType
    | SomeOtherParameter of SomeOtherParameterContentType
```

This way I could create a set and store the parameters there with a very nice data structure. The question here is: Given this idea, how would looking for a specific parameter look like? I don't know of any way to specify a predicate for a find-function for sets. It would be possible to define another sum type listing just the Parameter Types without their contents using this as key for a Dictionary but I don't like this idea too much. Using strings instead of the second sum type doesn't make things better as it still would require providing the list of possible parameters twice.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Thx
--Mathias.

Comment: I think the idea is the right one - but I don't get what you are looking for. You will probably have a `List<Parameter>` to work with and can just use [`List.tryFind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee353506.aspx) with something like `function (SomeParameter { Field1 = "find"; Field2 = _ }) -> true | _ -> false`?

Comment: @Carsten König: The parameters would be stored in a list (or set, for that matter) and I would want to retrieve one of the parameters from the list and read its values (so I don't know them).
So something like `tryFind(function (SomeParameter _) -> true | _ -> false)` might be a solution. I'd end up with a list of predicate functions `let someParameterPredicate = function (SomeParameter _) -> true | _ -> false` and then be able to use `tryFind someParameterPredicate`. Somewhat cumbersome still but doable and type safe. Interesting!

Comment: if you want to pick up the part you can use [`List.tryPick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee353814.aspx) (or `List.pick`) too - but yes you will need those functions. If this is to much you can always go the OOP route and use interfaces or dictionaries

Comment: @CarstenKönig: this should be an answer

Comment: For the record, I would prefer an approach where you have a DU for parameter types without content and a record type that would hold the content boxed. You'd give up some of the type safety, but get a less verbose and more flexible solution. But that's close to an approach you already dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you want is a tryFind for a Set:

```
module Set =

  let tryFind p =
    Set.toList >> List.tryFind p
```

Usage:

```
let mySet = Set.ofList [1;2;3;4;5]
let m = mySet |> Set.tryFind (fun t -> t = 2)
```

> val m : int option = Some 2

Usage with your Types:

```
let yourSet = Set.ofList [SomeParameter {Field1="hello";Field2=3}]
let mYours = yourSet |> Set.tryFind (fun t -> match t with
                                              |SomeParameter p -> true
                                              |SomeOtherParameter p -> false)
```

> val mYours : Parameter option = Some (SomeParameter {Field1 = "hello";
>                                                        Field2 = 3;})